# Restricting a user to only one row

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to develop an app for windows phone using azure mobile services. I am using authentication services provided by azure portal. After authentication the user needs to enter some data like his name, email id etc. The Problem I am facing is.. every time when the user enters different set of input values, it creates different rows for that particular user. I want to restrict the user with only one row so that he cant create more than one row. How can I do That.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check first if a row for this user is already present (using a "select", try to get a row with the user's ID), and if it finds one, just perform a update with new values. Otherwise you are free to insert a new row safely.

That means you will need to add a new column (in case you haven't already), that contains a unique user ID, that you can use to check if the user is already there.

Comment: You are welcome :-) . In case the solution is complete, please mark it as answer so that the question is displayed as resolved.

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind is you should use the UserId of the authenticated user and on the server side only. I.E. don't pass the userid from client side to the server side.